# Syntax error after restarting script from within itself

Tags: python, restart

I have a script that I need to restart every hour due to memory usage issues - I was not able to detect memory leaks unfortunately.
I have been using the following that works well:

```
os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + [sys.argv[0]])
```

However, every time it throws a syntax error when the code restarts (even though the code has been running fine for the previous hour). For instance the latest was on this line, which is syntactically correct:

```
value = f'{int(value):,}'
```

The code is running on Termius.
Has this occurred to anyone before? Is it related to the compiler?

Comment: Try `'python3'`?

Comment: Please edit the _full_ error message into your question, also show the value of `value`.

Comment: As @jonrsharpe suggested: Try `os.execv(sys.executable, ['python3'] + [sys.argv[0]])`